# Increment date with AWK for few days and months

Tags: linux, unix, date, csv, awk

**Increment date with AWK**

Hi all, I need your help. I have a file "test.csv" and I want to increase the dates for "6 months" and "10 days" so that I am getting the following output:

**test.csv:**

```
"000001","TEST1","2013-05-07 16:02:07","ACTIVE"
"000003","TEST3","2013-05-09 16:02:07","ACTIVE"
"000004","TEST4","2013-05-10 16:02:07","ACTIVE"
"000005","TEST5","2013-05-11 12:02:07","ACTIVE"
```

**Output test-increment-10days.csv:**

```
"000001","TEST1","2013-05-07 16:02:07","ACTIVE","2013-05-17 16:02:07"
"000003","TEST3","2013-05-09 16:02:07","ACTIVE","2013-05-19 16:02:07"
"000004","TEST4","2013-05-10 16:02:07","ACTIVE","2013-05-20 16:02:07"
"000005","TEST5","2013-05-11 12:02:07","ACTIVE","2013-05-21 12:02:07"
```

**Output test-increment-6months.csv:**

```
"000001","TEST1","2013-05-07 16:02:07","ACTIVE","2013-11-07 16:02:07"
"000003","TEST3","2013-05-09 16:02:07","ACTIVE","2013-11-09 16:02:07"
"000004","TEST4","2013-05-10 16:02:07","ACTIVE","2013-11-10 16:02:07"
"000005","TEST5","2013-05-11 12:02:07","ACTIVE","2013-11-11 12:02:07"
```

**I have tried it with this commands:**

> awk -F"\"*,\"*" '{{ cmd="date \"+%Y-%m-%d %T\" -d \""$3" +10 days\""; cmd | getline datum; close(cmd); print $0 ",\""datum"\""}}' test.csv > test-increment-10days.csv
>
> awk -F"\"*,\"*" '{{ cmd="date \"+%Y-%m-%d %T\" -d \""$3" +6 months\""; cmd | getline datum; close(cmd); print $0 ",\""datum"\""}}' test.csv > test-increment-6months.csv

but I am getting this wrong outputs.

**test-increment-10days.csv:**

```
"000001","TEST1","2013-05-07 16:02:07","ACTIVE","2013-05-08 16:02:07"
"000003","TEST3","2013-05-09 16:02:07","ACTIVE","2013-05-10 16:02:07"
"000004","TEST4","2013-05-10 16:02:07","ACTIVE","2013-05-11 16:02:07"
"000005","TEST5","2013-05-11 12:02:07","ACTIVE","2013-05-12 12:02:07"
```

**test-increment-6months.csv:**

```
"000001","TEST1","2013-05-07 16:02:07","ACTIVE","2013-06-07 16:02:07"
"000003","TEST3","2013-05-09 16:02:07","ACTIVE","2013-06-09 16:02:07"
"000004","TEST4","2013-05-10 16:02:07","ACTIVE","2013-06-10 16:02:07"
"000005","TEST5","2013-05-11 12:02:07","ACTIVE","2013-06-11 12:02:07"
```

The dates in "test-increment-10days.csv" are only incremented one day and in the "test-increment-6months.csv" only one month. Hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -F"\",\"" '{cmd="date -d \"$(date -d \""$3"\")+10days\" \"+%Y-%m-%d %T\"";cmd | getline datum; close(cmd); print $0 ",\""datum"\""}' test.csv > test-increment-10days.csv
```

An example of the underlying date command is:

```
date -d "$(date -d '2013-05-07 16:02:07')+10days" "+%Y-%m-%d %T"
```

There are two `date` commands. The inner `date` creates a date with a specified value. Then add 10 days to it. The outer date creates a new incremented date and formats it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`. You will first need to convert your requirements into seconds. Alternatively, write some `awk` to do this. This should get you up and running:

```
awk -f script.awk test.csv
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FPAT = "([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
    OFS=","
}

{
    string = "\"(....)-(..)-(..) (..):(..):(..)\""
    format = "\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4 \\5 \\6"

    date_spec = gensub(string, format, "", $3)
    timestamp = mktime(date_spec)

    # 10 days = 864000 seconds
    # 6 months = 15638400 seconds

    # uncomment one of the following:
#   new_stamp = "\"" strftime("%F %T", timestamp + 864000) "\""
#   new_stamp = "\"" strftime("%F %T", timestamp + 15638400) "\""

    print $0, new_stamp
}
```

Results:

```
"000001","TEST1","2013-05-07 16:02:07","ACTIVE","2013-05-17 16:02:07"
"000003","TEST3","2013-05-09 16:02:07","ACTIVE","2013-05-19 16:02:07"
"000004","TEST4","2013-05-10 16:02:07","ACTIVE","2013-05-20 16:02:07"
"000005","TEST5","2013-05-11 12:02:07","ACTIVE","2013-05-21 12:02:07"
```

Results:

```
"000001","TEST1","2013-05-07 16:02:07","ACTIVE","2013-11-04 16:02:07"
"000003","TEST3","2013-05-09 16:02:07","ACTIVE","2013-11-06 16:02:07"
"000004","TEST4","2013-05-10 16:02:07","ACTIVE","2013-11-07 16:02:07"
"000005","TEST5","2013-05-11 12:02:07","ACTIVE","2013-11-08 12:02:07"
```

Comment: +1 Nice use of FPAT and built in functions. Though will work for GAWK version 4 or later because of FPAT.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate version of [dogbane's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16936390/5291015) with lesser quoting and using a simplified `date` construct would be

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FPAT = "([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
    OFS=","
}
{   
    gsub(/["]/,"",$3);
    cmd = "date -d \""$3" 10 days\" \"+%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p\"" 
}
{
    cmd|getline D; close(cmd);
    $3="\042"D"\042"
}1' file
```

and for 6 months would be

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FPAT = "([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
    OFS=","
}
{   
    gsub(/["]/,"",$3);
    cmd = "date -d \""$3" 6 months\" \"+%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p\"" 
}
{
    cmd|getline D; close(cmd);
    $3="\042"D"\042"
}1' file
```

The enhancements done are:

1. A fewer quotes while forming the command string `cmd` for the date compute, which makes it elegant to use in the `getline` function of `awk`.
2. Making use of the `date -d<date-string> 10 days`, without using the `+` operator.
3. Adding `FPAT` regex construct for a more strict parsing of the individual CSV fields.