# unix awk subtracting integer field from month of date field

Tags: shell, date, unix, awk

I have a file with around 10MM records.  Here is my dateSample src file:

```
0000000566 2017/01/01 0
0000000055 2017/01/01 0
0000000109 2017/01/01 1
0000000940 2017/01/01 0
0000000566 2017/01/01 1
0000000055 2017/01/01 1
0000000109 2017/01/01 2
```

I essentially need to subtract the last integer value off of the month in the date and print the new value without the integer, thus:

```
0000000566 2017/01/01
0000000055 2017/01/01
0000000109 2016/12/01
0000000940 2017/01/01
0000000566 2016/12/01
0000000055 2016/12/01
0000000109 2016/11/01
```

I've been having real troubles with date (or gdate on macOS whilst testing) and been searching in vain for the last couple of days.
It's either prefixing with a zero and dropping the m and d values:

```
awk '{ print (gdate -d $2 +"%Y/%m/%d") }' <$src
```

or suffixing with a zero and subtracting the integer from the year:

```
awk '{ print (gdate -d $2 +-$3 months +"%Y/%m/%d") }' <$src
```

or mashing the whole thing together still isn't correct:

```
awk '{ print gdate -d (gdate -d $2 +"%Y/%m/%d") +-$3 months +"%Y/%m/%d" }' <$src
```

I found the following excellent response: 
    [Increment date with AWK for few days and months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935886/increment-date-with-awk-for-few-days-and-months/16936390#16936390)
which is doing exactly what I want, but it is running very very slow which I'm assuming is because of a command within a command.

Here is current awk (I'm using gdate because I'm running on macOS BSD for now):

```
awk '{ cmd=" gdate -d \"$(gdate -d \""$2"\")+\"-"$3"\"months\" \"+%Y/%m/%d\" ";
       cmd | getline fmtDate; close(cmd); 
       print $1, fmtDate
     }' <$src
```

So I basically need that output in a performant way.
Thanks in advance for any guidance / rewrite.
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `awk` supports [time functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html#Time-Functions) `mktime` and `strftime` (which are a GNU extension), you can simply do it like this:

```
awk -F'[ /]' '{print $1 " " strftime("%Y/%m/%d", mktime($2" "($3-$5)" "$4" 0 0 0"))}' file
```

First we convert the date into a Unix timestamp. `mktime` accepts dates only in `"YYYY MM DD HH MM SS"` format, that's why we need to construct it manually. But it does the normalization automatically, and it will happily convert `"2017 -1 1 0 0 0"` to the same timestamp as `"2016 11 1 0 0 0"`.

After that we just need to convert the timestamp to "y/m/d" format and print it.

---

Or, you could do the date arithmetic "by hand" in the simple case that doesn't require date normalization -- if the day of the month is always `<= 28`. (For days greater that `28`, like `31`, you would also need to add clipping/clamping or overflowing to the script below, but then you would have to take care of leap years, etc.)

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS = "[ /]";
}

{
    mm = $2 * 12 + ($3 - 1) - $5;
    y = int(mm / 12);
    m = mm % 12 + 1;
    d = $4;
    printf("%s %04d/%02d/%02d\n", $1, y, m, d);
}
```

So, the idea is simple. We split the line on spaces and slashes, so we can convert year/month into a total number of months (`12 * y + m`). Then we subtract the month from the last column and convert the total number of months back to year/month via `divmod` operation.

Output:

```
$ ./script.awk file
0000000566 2017/01/01
0000000055 2017/01/01
0000000109 2016/12/01
0000000940 2017/01/01
0000000566 2016/12/01
0000000055 2016/12/01
0000000109 2016/11/01
```

Comment: Awesome response ... thank you for detailed explanation.  
The strftime-mktime combo is very nice and is working super-fast.  
Thanks also for the 'by hand' version for completeness.
Thank you for your help.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Since you are manipulating dates, it is better to do this in shell itself:

```
while read -r str date n; do
   echo "$str $(date -d "$(date -d $date) -$n months" '+%Y/%m/%d')"
done < file

0000000566 2017/01/01
0000000055 2017/01/01
0000000109 2016/12/01
0000000940 2017/01/01
0000000566 2016/12/01
0000000055 2016/12/01
0000000109 2016/11/01
```

Comment: Won't this also be slow, since you're calling external `date` on each line (twice)?

Comment: Also, shouldn't your inner call to `date` be: `$(date -d "$date" '+%Y/%m/%d')`?

Comment: Thanks @randomir it is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

try one more simple way to solve this problem.

```
awk 'BEGIN{
     split("01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12", month,",")
}
{
     split($2, array,"/");
       if(array[2]<=$3){
       array[2]=array[2]+12-$3;
       array[1]=array[1]-1
      }
       else{
       array[2]-$3
      };
     print $1,array[1]"/"array[2]"/"array[3]
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Hi ... thanks for the above but it wasn't working for date of, say, 2017-05-01.  Here is a tweaked version:      

awk '{
 split($2, array,"/");
 if($3 > 0) {
     if(array[2] == "01") {
         array[1] = array[1] - 1
         array[2] = array[2] + 12 - $3;
         if(array[2] < 10) { array[2] = "0" array[2] }
     } else {
      array[2] = array[2] - $3
         if(array[2] < 10) { array[2] = "0" array[2] }
     };
 }
 print $1, array[1] "/" array[2] "/" array[3]
 }' <$src

Cheers