# Using awk to add one month to a date

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a file 1.txt like below:

```
"15227962157615645"$"2018-12-04 06:55:43"
"15227525816721347"$"2018-12-03 18:48:11"
```

I can get the date using:

```
awk -F\" '{print $4}' 1.txt
```

Additionally I need add one month to the date. For the above input my desired output would be:

```
2019-01-04 06:55:43
2019-01-03 18:48:11
```

I tried to use

```
awk -F\" '{print date -d "$4 +1 month"+%Y-%m-%d}' 1.txt
```

but it does not work.

Comment: What shell are you using? Is it ok with bash?

Comment: I use bash. it does not work

Comment: @oliv I want use bash or awk to get a date from a file and then add a month, then save to a new file.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16936390/3832970 and https://ideone.com/XBpjwK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk has limited support for date calculation, so here is a bash only solution relying on the `date` command:

```
IFS='$';
while read n t; do 
  printf '%s$"%s"\n' "$n" "$(date -d "${t//\"/} +1 month" '+%F %T')"
done <file
```

The input field separator is set to `$` to get the time into `$t` variable.

The double quote of the date field are removed using bash parameter expansion `${t//\"/}`.

This allows to pass the `+1 month` key word to `date`.

Then the `printf` prints back to the original format of the input file.