# Increment date based on time

Tags: date, awk, sed

I need to increment a date by +1d based on the time.  This seems to be a bit over my head but I suspect it can be done with perl or maybe even awk.  For every timestamp with 0000, I need to increment the day by +1.

input:

```
15,07/31/2020 1600,1048,31,0
15,07/31/2020 1700,1086,45,0
15,07/31/2020 1800,1092,42,0
15,07/31/2020 1900,1017,20,1
15,07/31/2020 2000,945,0,28
15,07/31/2020 2100,897,0,43
15,07/31/2020 2200,869,0,55
15,07/31/2020 2300,812,0,72
15,07/31/2020 0000,778,0,82
```

expected output:

```
15,07/31/2020 1600,1048,31,0
15,07/31/2020 1700,1086,45,0
15,07/31/2020 1800,1092,42,0
15,07/31/2020 1900,1017,20,1
15,07/31/2020 2000,945,0,28
15,07/31/2020 2100,897,0,43
15,07/31/2020 2200,869,0,55
15,07/31/2020 2300,812,0,72
15,08/01/2020 0000,778,0,82
```

It looks like awk can increment date but my question is how do I only increment the date on the lines with 0000 while still printing out the rest of the lines unaltered?

Comment: Right now I'm working with sed.  
`sed -i '/0000/s/07/08/g' file.csv > newfile.csv`
This finds the string and replaces the month.  However I'm unsure how to get it to dynamically detect the date and add a single day.

Comment: I'm also looking at awk https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935886/increment-date-with-awk-for-few-days-and-months  The challenge with this seems to be that it indiscriminately affects all dates

Comment: In order to increment the day, you also need to roll over the month if necessary. For that, you need to know the number of days in the month. To know that, you also need to know if the current year is a leap year (i.e. february has either 28 or 29 days). The formula is readily available with a web search. I'm not sure about the format of your input: `15,07/31/2020 0000,778,0,82` What is the `15`? I assume you just pass it through. What is the `0000,778,0,82`? I assume you can just compare the first number [as text] with `0000`. See: https://pastebin.com/Tz6xhuRv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Perl solution uses Time::Piece (that is included in the standard distribution).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds 'ONE_DAY';

my $regex = '(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d) (\d{4})';

while (<>) {    # reads from the input file supplied on the CLI
    my ($mdy, $time) = /$regex/;
    if ($time eq '0000') {
        # parse the date ($mdy) and add 1 day
        my $date = Time::Piece->strptime($mdy, "%m/%d/%Y") + ONE_DAY;

        # convert the Time::Piece object to a string rep
        $date = $date->strftime("%m/%d/%Y");

        # substitute the new date for the date 1 day earlier
        s/$regex/$date $time/;
    }
    print;
}
```

Prints

```
C:\Old_Data\perlp>perl test3.pl f0.txt
15,07/31/2020 1600,1048,31,0
15,07/31/2020 1700,1086,45,0
15,07/31/2020 1800,1092,42,0
15,07/31/2020 1900,1017,20,1
15,07/31/2020 2000,945,0,28
15,07/31/2020 2100,897,0,43
15,07/31/2020 2200,869,0,55
15,07/31/2020 2300,812,0,72
15,08/01/2020 0000,778,0,82
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk:

```
awk '$5=="0000"{
       # convert columns to unixtime
       unixtime=mktime($4 " " $2 " " $3 " " "00 00 00")

       # add one day to unixtime and convert back to month/day/year
       nextday=strftime("%m/%d/%Y",unixtime+60*60*24)

       # rebuild current row
       $0=$1 OFS nextday " " $5 OFS $6 OFS $7 OFS $8
     }
     {print}' FS='[,/ ]' OFS=',' file
```

As one line:

```
awk '$5=="0000"{unixtime=mktime($4 " " $2 " " $3 " " "00 00 00"); nextday=strftime("%m/%d/%Y",unixtime+60*60*24); print $1,nextday " " $5,$6,$7,$8; next}{print}' FS='[,/ ]' OFS=',' file
```

Output:

```
15,07/31/2020 1600,1048,31,0
15,07/31/2020 1700,1086,45,0
15,07/31/2020 1800,1092,42,0
15,07/31/2020 1900,1017,20,1
15,07/31/2020 2000,945,0,28
15,07/31/2020 2100,897,0,43
15,07/31/2020 2200,869,0,55
15,07/31/2020 2300,812,0,72
15,08/01/2020 0000,778,0,82
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – **FS**, **OFS**, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 1):

*Note:* This is prefaced by my top comment. Since this question has been reopened, I can post the answer here.

In order to increment the day, we also need to roll over the month if necessary.

For that, we need to know the number of days in the month.

To know that, we also need to know if the current year is a leap year (i.e. february has either 28 or 29 days). The formula is readily available with a web search.

I'm not sure about the format of your input:

```
15,07/31/2020 0000,778,0,82
```

What is the `15`? I assume you just pass it through.

What is the `0000,778,0,82`? I assume you can just compare the first number [as text] with `0000`.

---

Here's the code in `perl`. I've coded the entire algorithm *without* any reliance on installing extra perl packages or use of functions such as `mktime`, etc. I've tried to annotate it as much as possible:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# code to increment day

master(@ARGV);
exit(0);

sub master
{

    my(@days_in_month) = (31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31);

    # input format:
    #   15,07/31/2020 0000,778,0,82
    while ($buf = <STDIN>) {
        chomp($buf);

        # split off date and time
        my($date,$time) = split(" ",$buf);

        # split up date
        my($pre,$mon,$day,$year) = split(m%[,/]%,$date);

        # decide if current year is leap year
        my($isleap) = 0;
        {
            # year must be divisible by 4
            last if (($year % 4) != 0);

            # if year is divisible by 100, it is _not_ a leap year unless ...
            if (($year % 100) == 0) {
                # ... it is also divisible by 400
                last if (($year % 400) != 0);
            }

            $isleap = 1;
        }

        # get number of days in february
        if ($isleap) {
            $days_in_month[1] = 29;
        }
        else {
            $days_in_month[1] = 28;
        }

        # change only if time is 0000
        if ($time =~ /^0000,/) {
            # increment day
            $day += 1;

            # advance month if necessary
            if ($day > $days_in_month[$mon - 1]) {
                $day = 1;
                $mon += 1;
            }

            # advance year if necessary
            if ($mon > 12) {
                $mon = 1;
                $year += 1;
            }
        }

        $date = sprintf("%2.2d,%2.2d/%2.2d/%4.4d",$pre,$mon,$day,$year);

        printf("%s %s\n",$date,$time);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really useful and thank you for pointing out the leap year caveat.  While I ended up using the shorter script below, I'm also archiving this one as well due to the well laid out format and articulate/helpful annotations.  I wish I could give you an answer mark too.  Regardless, thank you so much for the help!!!

Comment: You're welcome! As I mentioned, I deliberately avoided canned helper functions to show how to do it manually. Particularly since others were using them. No worries. You should [always] accept the _best_ answer. But, [if you haven't already done so], you can _upvote_ more than one _good_ answer.